# TypeError 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

i use make_id to make id think but i got error: TypeError 'type' object is not iterable
i dont no why i got this error,can any person help me?
i am Chinese(Taiwan)
my code:

```
from msilib import make_id
from tkinter import simpledialog,Tk
def number():
    win = make_id('')
def winner_number():
    numberd = 'c4'
def get_task():
    task=simpledialog.askstring("id製造器",'你要製造id嗎?')
    return task
def get_message():
    message=simpledialog.askstring('你的id是:',number,'中獎號碼:',winner_number)
    return message
screen = Tk()

while True:
    task=get_task()
    if task == "要":
        massage= get_message
        number = make_id
        if number(str) in winner_number():
            print('你的運氣超好!!')
    elif task=='cancel':
        print('你失敗了!!')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You are effectively executing `make_id(str)` and that function most likely doesn't know how to process it. You probably wanted to do `number = make_id()` or pass some arguments there.

Comment: i run the code with no error.  Can you please show the error or how to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

the code is have multiple errors but let me intrudes few of them 
1 how functions values work in python

```py
def function(values)
    print(values)

function(10)

# 2nd way
def functions(values)
    return values
a = function(10)
print(function(10))
# will give same result
```

so basically you are trying to do is just run stuff in function

```py
def numebr():
   win = make_id('')
def winner_number():
   numberd = 'c4'
```

but you are comparing two function..
instade you could do

```py
def number():
   return make_id('')
def winner_number():
   return 'c4'

if number() == winner_number():
    print('you win')
```

Comment: i use your code and i got new error :IndexError
string index out of range

Comment: I told this code have multiple errors. you ask for the 'type' error than this is your ans